# Accordion component in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am looking to find a way to implement an accordion component in swing. So far wherever I have looked I cannot seem to find anything that is native swing.

The only I found was a solution that revolves around having a TreePane from FX embedded to a swing component but my question is, there something that is native to swing and can act like this?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) and [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout)

Comment: They do look really neat but I need something that does not utilize third party libraries or code.

Comment: Then you're going to have to have a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more informaiton about the `glassPane` and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for how to animate it

Comment: If you're considering embedding a JavaFX control into swing ([which can be done](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html)), then I would think [`Accordion`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html) would be a better fit than `TreeView`. OTOH, if you're comfortable adapting a tree control as an accordion, then why not just use `JTree`?

Comment: There is a native Swing version on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/Guppster/Swing-Tools/blob/master/src/com/petersoft/advancedswing/accordion/Accordion.java).  It isn't perfect, but could serve as inspiration.

Comment: There is another one [here](https://github.com/oliverwatkins/swing_library)